# CSV file to DataTable to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to read 2 separate `.CSV` files in a C# application and bulk copy them into SQL Server. I have searched online a lot, but don't seem to find a simple workable solution.

The files are extremely large (around 50000 rows and 15-20 columns).

I am trying to use CsvHelper library to read files. When I try to read the csv file, this is the error message that I get:
"CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException: The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: 'ASPH-G'
    MemberType: System.Double
    TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DoubleConverter'"

How can I solve this issue. I am presenting my Runway class, as well as the code for reading the file below. What can I do differently?

```
public class Runway
    {
        [Index(0)]
        public int RunwayId { get;set; }
        [Index(1)]
        public int AirportId { get; set; }
        [Index(7)]
        public int RunwayStatus { get; set; }
        [Index(8)]
        public string LEId {get;set;}
        [Index(9)]
        [Optional]

        public double? LELatitude {get; set;}
        [Index(10)]
        [Optional]
        public double? LELongitude {get; set;}
        [Index(14)]
        public string HEId {get; set;}
        [Index(15)]
        [Optional]
        public double? HELatitude {get;set;}
        [Index(16)]
        [Optional]
        public double? HELongitude {get;set;}

        public Airport Airport { get; set; }


    }
```

Code for reading file:

```
var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration
                {
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    HeaderValidated = null,
                    MissingFieldFound = null,
                    IgnoreBlankLines = false
                };


                using (var reader = new StreamReader ("../runways.csv"))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
                {
                    var runways = csv.GetRecords<Runway>().ToList();
                }
```

How do I use typeconverter in CsvHelper to get this working?

Comment: Yes there are many tutorials on how to use SqlBulkCopy to insert a csv file. For example this one https://johnnycode.com/2013/08/19/using-c-sharp-sqlbulkcopy-to-import-csv-data-sql-server/ What doesn't work for you? Please ask a precise question with context about your problem

Comment: What is the code have you tried and errors?

Comment: I have tried many things, now I am stuck on SQL server connection string.